# Paddings for <span>

Tags: html, css, padding

`span` tag currently have both to vertical and horizontal `padding` on the page. I tried to play with it and made sure that they are applied to both dimensions.

So if `span` is an inline element and supposed to not have vertical paddings, why it's been added vertically? Is that because it's inside a block element div? Or any other reason?

Thanks in advance.

```css
span {
  padding: 2rem 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h4>
    <span> Some text </span>
  </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: What style rules are being applied to the `h4`?

Comment: give a border to h4 and a background to span, ...and be more confused .  https://jsfiddle.net/8zs5d0fa/

Comment: Add display:inline-block; on span tag

Comment: Or `display: block` would be fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<span>` elements are `display: inline` by default. Inline means, the text will stay in the same line with everything else that's in your `<h4>` (as long as your h4 does not have any special stylings)

So in your case, padding (and also margin) can be added. But only `left` and `right` values are added. `top` and `bottom` are added, but ignored by the h4 element.

This results in staying in the same `line` (thus `INline`) with the h4. But the div (where the h4 is inside) will still grow to the bottom.
Sadly I can't explain why it's not growing to the top and pushing the h4 down.

I've made an example for you with ridiculos high top/bottom padding and margin:

```css
span {
    padding: 100rem 5rem;
    margin: 100rem 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div> 
    <h4>
      H4 with a special <span>WORD </span> inside!
    </h4> 
    <p>
    Something else
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: give a background-color to the span to check where it stands ;) https://jsfiddle.net/8zs5d0fa/

Comment: Thanks guys. I failed to connect the dots and that confused me making me think that I have a wrong theory.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus nice trippy backgrounds ;)

Answer (score 0):

`span` won't have `padding` because it is an `inline` element by default, so set `inline-block` or `block`.

```css
#idk {
  padding: 60px;
  display: inline-block; /* or block */
  background: green
}
```

```html
<span id="idk">idk</span>
```